# Arduino C Code not working

Tags: arduino, lcd

```cpp
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int rs = 13, en = 12, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
    // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    // Print a message to the LCD.
    lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
    // Turn on the display:
    lcd.display();
    delay(500);
}
```

**Arduino Board:**
[image]

I tried several times and it would not work for me.

My results were:

Comment: Please add more details about what you're trying to do, and what the error is.  External image links may age away, and leave the question useless.

Comment: `"it would not work for me."` What does this mean - what were your results (you can edit them into your question)!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a display where you need to adjust the contrast ?

BTW: I won't check your picture, if the wires between Arduino and display are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding lcd.display() to your setup.